# Ways to make a 2D physics simulator for a side scrolling game

Tags: c#, xna, physics-engine

To start out I want to say I am making a 2D side scrolling video game. The game is coded in C# and the framework is with XNA. I was wondering what is an easy way to make a basic physics engine might be, and where to put it. My experience with XNA isn't to extensive but I know enough to make a game without physics, so naturally the now I wish to add physics (a jump feature that then pulls the player down). My goal is to end up with similar physics to Terraria or Super Mario. Any ideas on where to start? I know I will need at least a vector to pull the player down and another to push the player up, but thats as much as I know....

Comment: Start on codeplex or Github, find existing engine, there are lots of.  Until, of course,  your goal is to learn how to build physics engine.

Comment: My goal is to build something light weight and some what simple. I dont want to spend days on building this. Even though I know I could very easily do that. I looked on google and all I could really find were physics engines that were huge and were rather complex to integrate.

Comment: There are plenty of game engine and physic tutorial online. They are a better place to start this sort of endeavor. Then, when an *actual* problem is encountered (for which there is not an existing question), a post to SO would be more appropriate.

Comment: I am going to try using this as a base for a physics engine for now.
http://gamedev.tutsplus.com/tutorials/implementation/create-custom-2d-physics-engine-aabb-circle-impulse-resolution/

Comment: by your sentece that you don't want to spend days on building something, i guess you need MagicGameMaker. you just download models and music and put all together is this app... few clicks and voilà!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you need the player to push things around and by physics, you mean just jumping, then implementing jumping as in traditional sidescrollers is simple.

You might want to do something like this:

```
float currentYspeed;
float GRAVITY = 5;
bool playerFlying;

// In Update():
if (isUpArrowKeyDown() && !playerFlying) { playerFlying = true currentYspeed = 50; }
playerY += currentYspeed;
currentYspeed -= GRAVITY;
if (playerCollidesWithFloor())
{
  currentYspeed = 0; // We came back to ground.
  playerFlying = false;
}
else if (playerCollidesWithSomethingElse())
{
  currentYSpeed = 0; // We hit obstacle in-air.
}
```

Of course, you might want to refactor and beautify this code, make the position and velocity changes dependent on seconds elapsed etc.

If you don't know how to implement the collision functions, consider reading up on keywords "2D collision detection" or "sidescroller/platformer tutorial".